# C# - I want to listen to a group in Telegram from more than one program

Tags: c#, telegram

I can listen to a group through a program, but I want to listen to the same group with more than one program at the same time.

thanks in advance

---

```
static ITelegramBotClient botClient = new TelegramBotClient("123456789:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");

botClient.OnMessage += Bot_OnMesaage;
botClient.StartReceiving();

public void Bot_OnMesaage(object sender, Telegram.Bot.Args.MessageEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Message.Type == Telegram.Bot.Types.Enums.MessageType.Text)
    {
        Debug(e.Message.Text);              
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to a [Telegram.Bot FAQ](https://telegrambots.github.io/book/FAQ.html) (409 error section) you can't duplicate the messages that you get by long-polling (and I assume that in your case you're long-polling telegram for getting updates) so you can't make multiple instances of your bot like that.

The possible way is to create a webhook provided either by your own internet server that will process messages from telegram or by something like [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) tunnel to multiple instances.

Comment: Thank you for your interest. it was very clear and precise